# MPI Program using MPI_Scatter and MPI_Reduce

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, computer-science

Write an MPI program that efficiently compute the sum of array elements.
Program 1: Tasks communicate with MPI_Scatter and MPI_Reduce.

1. The programs can assume that the number of processes is a power of two.
2. The programs should add 2^15 = 65536 random doubles in the range 0 to 100.
   Task 0 must generate the numbers, store them in array and distribute them to the tasks.
3. Each task does a serial sum of the numbers it is assigned. The local sums are then
   added together using a tree structured parallel sum.
4. After the parallel sum is complete, task 0 should compute a serial sum of the
   same numbers (to verify the result).
5. Task 0 must print the parallel sum, the serial sum and the time required for the
   parallel sum (including data distribution).

Comment: SO is not a place where you can simply dump your homework. please share your efforts!

Comment: I tried but my code is not running.

Comment: I did not see any code

Comment: I have posted my code. I was able to do it with MPI_Send and MPI_Recv. But having problem with scatter and reduce.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); // Initialize the MPI environment
int rank; 
int comm_size;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&comm_size);

int number1[2];           
int number[4];
if(rank == 0){
  number[0]=1;
  number[1]=2;
  number[2]=3;
  number[3]=4;   
  //number[4]=5;            
 }



double local_start, local_finish, local_elapsed, elapsed;
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
local_start = MPI_Wtime();


//All processes
 MPI_Scatter(number, 2, MPI_INT, &number1, 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//printf("I'm process %d , I received the array : ",rank);
   
int sub_sum = 0;
for(int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){
   // printf("%d ",number1[i]);
    sub_sum = sub_sum + number1[i];
}
printf("\n");        
int sum = 0;
MPI_Reduce(&sub_sum, &sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);            
local_finish = MPI_Wtime();
local_elapsed = local_finish -local_start;
MPI_Reduce(&local_elapsed,&elapsed,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_MAX,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);


   if(rank == 0)
{
  printf("\nthe sum of array is: %d\n",sum);
  printf("Elapsed time = %e seconds\n",elapsed);
}
 


MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: how many MPI tasks are you running? what kind of issues are you facing?

Comment: You have hard-coded certain restrictions on the number of processes. I would insert an assert that `number` is long enough.